# How to use Redemption to open an Exchange shared mailbox sent folder and display it

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I'm attempting to use Redemption to display an Exchange shared mailbox sent folder.

For instance I can open the inbox, contacts, or calendar folder without Redemption as follows.

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
string recipientName = "SharedAccountName@MyCompany.com";
Outlook.Recipient recip = ns.CreateRecipient(recipientName);
recip.Resolve();

if (recip.Resolved)
{
  Outlook.MAPIFolder InboxFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
  //Outlook.MAPIFolder ContactsFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
  //Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
  InboxFolder.Display();
}
```

But since olFolderSentMail cannot be specified as an argument I'm attempting to use Redemption to display the sent folder. Reference-
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.getshareddefaultfolder.aspx

So here's the code I'm attempting but I can't figure out how to .Display(); the folder using Redemption or if it's even possible.

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
string recipientName = "SharedAccountName@MyCompany.com";
Outlook.Recipient recip = ns.CreateRecipient(recipientName);
recip.Resolve();

Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;

if (recip.Resolved)
 {
   Redemption.RDOFolder Sentfolder = session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
   Sentfolder. // There's no Intellisense for Display
 }
```

---

Update: Dmity was correct but I still needed Redemption get the entryid and storeid for the Sent shared mailbox folder because I could not retrieve it using the _NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder. Here's what I ended up doing, hopefully it helps someone else.

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
string recipientName = "anExchangeEmailAddress@yourCompany.com";        
Outlook.Recipient recip = ns.CreateRecipient(recipientName);
recip.Resolve();
Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;

 if (recip.Resolved)
  {
    Redemption.RDOFolder Sentfolder = session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
    string folderID = Sentfolder.EntryID;
    string storeID = Sentfolder.StoreID;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder displaySent = ns.GetFolderFromID(folderID, storeID);
    displaySent.Display();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders are displayed by Outlook, there is no pure MAPI API for that. You can reopen the folder in OOM using `Namespace.GetFolderFromID`, then call `MAPIFolder.Display`.

Comment: As always, Thanks Dmitry! I still needed to use Redemption to get the StoreID and EntryID for the shared Sent folder.